# Disabling play.jobs.Job from running while in test mode in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

Using play framework 1.2.4 with scala.
I have few play jobs that looks like like

```
@OnApplicationStart class MyOtherJob extends Job {  ...  } 

@Every("30s")  class MyJob extends Job {  ...  }
```

These jobs are running while the application is in test mode, so they 
mess up things. 
How can I disable them from running while testing?

I tried the following application config, didn't help:

```
# Jobs executor 
# ~~~~~~ 
# Size of the Jobs pool 
play.jobs.pool=10 
test.play.jobs.pool=0 
test.cron.queue.every=never 
dev.cron.queue.every=20s 
prod.cron.queue.every=20s 
test.cron.onApplicationStart.trigger=never 
dev.cron.onApplicationStart.trigger=auto 
prod.cron.onApplicationStart.trigger=auto
```

Comment: try asking in the google group https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework or file a bug https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/overview, the test.cron.onApplicationStart.trigger=never should work, create a ticket for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to check if Play is running in test mode using the following syntax.

```
play.Play.runingInTestMode()
```

**Note:** the spelling mistake is not accidental. That is the method name in the API.

Therefore, in your Jobs, you should be able to wrap the job execution around an IF statement using the above, and therefore, preventing test mode jobs.

Comment: I agree. There may be, but I am not aware of it. This is an easy enough workaround though.

Comment: Is there a way to know if we're in dev/prod?

Comment: `play.Play.Mode.isDev()` and `play.Play.Mode.isProd()`

Comment: Sorry for the necromancy, @Codemwnci. Which is better: Your suggestion, or `Play.configuration.get()` ? I think your is better, because its cleaner.

Comment: i prefer the helper methods...and if the result `Play.configuration.get()` ever changes, the helper methods should be expected to change with it...so its cleaner, and safer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ugh, my formatting is off.  Will fix in a bit.

We have a nice little wrapper that checks if a job is enabled in a specific environment.

Example entry in application.conf

`job.myjob.enabled=true
%test.job.myjob.enabled=false
%prod.job.myjob.enabled=true`

and so on.

`def ifEnabled(property: String)(runnable: => Unit) =
    play.conf.configuration.getProperty(property + ".enabled", "false") match {
        case "true" => runnable
        case _ => Logger info "Ignoring " + property + " since it's disabled!"
    }`

Then in your job

`class MyJob extends Job {
    ifEnabled("job.myJob") {
        // code goes here
    }
}`

This way you don't have to check each individual environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Every.class)) {
                try {
                    Job job = (Job) clazz.newInstance();
                    scheduledJobs.add(job);
                    String value = job.getClass().getAnnotation(Every.class).value();
                    if (value.startsWith("cron.")) {
                        value = Play.configuration.getProperty(value);
                    }
                    value = Expression.evaluate(value, value).toString();
                    if(!"never".equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
                        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(job, Time.parseDuration(value), Time.parseDuration(value), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
```

so you should define cron.myjob=3min %test.cron.myjob=never and on("cron.myjob")

ex:

```
cron.SyncWeixinInfo=never
%prod.cron.SyncWeixinInfo=0 0 0 1 * ?
%test.cron.SyncWeixinInfo=0 0 0 1 * ?
%localtest.cron.SyncWeixinInfo=0 0 0 1 * ?
%prodSlave.cron.SyncWeixinInfo=never


@On("cron.SyncWeixinInfo")//每月1号凌晨0点
public class SyncWeixinInfo extends Job {
```